# GTINs (Global Trade Item Numbers) - Database New requirement for Google shopping

Tags: data-request, products

I recently realized that Google will make it mandatory to have a list of GTIN numbers for each product you do e-commerce for on Google Shopping (See details [here](https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/6352134?hl=en)).

Is there any way to easily obtain these numbers or a database where I can search for the ones which correspond to the products I work with (Luxury watches)?

Here you can see more detailed information on the [unique  identifiers.](https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/160161)